# Artist's block or artist block, which is correct?

Tags: grammar, expressions, comparisons

I've always thought [artist's block](https://www.google.com/search?q=artist%27s%20block&client=firefox-b-e&ei=najjYLHAHI3l9QO1g4_YBw&oq=artist%27s%20block&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADIECAAQHjoHCAAQRxCwA0oECEEYAFDK9wtYyvcLYLD5C2gBcAJ4AIABsgGIAeMCkgEDMC4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjxgvPcnM3xAhWNcn0KHbXBA3sQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) was correct but then when doing some research recently I've also stumbled upon [artist block](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22artist%20block%22&client=firefox-b-e&ei=danjYPLMMsae9QPt-oKQBw&oq=%22artist%20block%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDOggILhDHARCvAUoECEEYAFCtW1i9YGDBYmgBcAJ4AIAB3AGIAckEkgEFMC4xLjKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiy24jEnc3xAhVGT30KHW29AHIQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) (without apostrophe "s") quite a bit too. They can't both be correct can they? Which one is correct grammatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so much what is grammatically correct as which term is most commonly used. In this case *google ngram* searches of published writing can be useful.

I ran an ngram search for the phrases [writer's block, writer block, artist block and artist's block](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Writer%27s+block%2Cwriter+block%2Cartist%27s+block%2Cartist+block&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) and found that *writer's block* is so much more common than the other  three that it makes comparison between the other three impossible.

I, therefore, ran a search for [writer block, artist block and artist's block](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=writer+block%2Cartist%27s+block%2Cartist+block&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) and found that, of those three, *artist's block* was by far the most common.

*Artist's block* is quite uncommon but the phrases *artist block* and *writer block* are so uncommon that they can safely be considered to be unused if not incorrect. I shall continue to use *writer's block* and I may start to use *artist's block* which I had not previously encountered but I shall shun *writer block* and *artist block* completely as mis-writings of the possessive terms.